# Entity Framework Code First - Mapping entites from another database to include in model

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, mapping, ef-code-first

I've been tasked with creating a sub application of an existing site. The sub application needs to make use of the users in the parent site but this is under a different database.

I'm using Entity Framework code first for the new site. However, I wish to create a mapping between the parent database user table and the new code first database.

Is this possible?

- ParantDB.dbo.User
- SubDB.dbo.Order
- SubDB.dbo.OrderItems

  ```
  public class Order
  {
     public int OrderId { get; set; }
     public User Customer { get; set; } // Maintains a relationship user table  
  }

  public class User
  {
     public int UserId { get; set; }
     ....
  }
  ```

  > public class SubSiteContext : DbContext 
  >     {
  >
  > ```
  >      public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
  >      public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
  >
  >      protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  >      {
  >           //???? I Presume I need to do the mapping here??
  >      }
  > }
  > ```

Answer (score 1):

Context can be bound only to a single connection string = single database. The workaround for this cab be for example creating database view in your `SubDB` which will internally hide query to `ParentDB.dbo.Users` and map this view in the same way as you map tables.